# How to index a XML file with Lucene

Tags: java, xml, indexing, lucene

how the create lucene index following xml file with any sample code.
 so I can search for cloth name as well as its color and sale type.

```
<cloths>
   <cloth color="red">shirt</cloth>
   <cloth color="green" sale="Y">shirt</cloth>
   <cloth color="orange">jeans</cloth>
</cloths>
```

Is there a way to use Lucene to do this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17206203/appache-lucene-indexing-of-large-xml-file

Comment: Reformatted question for readability.